# Why isn't my Ruby object deleted when the last reference goes out of scope?

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks, scoping

I've found a weird effect when trying to track down a memory leak in a Rails app. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Save this script as a plain Ruby script (Rails not necessary):

```
class Fnord
    def to_s
        'fnord'
    end
end

def test
    f = Fnord.new
end

test

GC.start
sleep 2

ObjectSpace.each_object do |o|
    puts o if o.is_a? Fnord
end
```

When I run this via

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i486-linux]
```

I get the following:

```
bash $ ruby var_test
fnord
```

Although the variable f is out of scope, there are no other references to the single Fnord object, and I've garbage collected, the object still seems to exist. Is this a nefarious memory leak of some sort, or am I completely missing something about Ruby?

Further, if I change the test method to this:

```
def test
    f = Fnord.new
    f = nil
end
```

I get no output. But surely this should not change the semantics here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the difference between your two versions is not about the value of f, but about the fact that in your first version `test` will return the new Fnord object while in the second version `test` will return `nil`.

As a matter of fact the object will be garbage collected if any value comes between `Fnord.new` and `GC.start`. For example simply adding a line `42` between the call to `test` and the call to `GC.start` will cause the object to be collected.

I'm not sure why this is the case, but I suspect that the ruby interpreter holds on to the value of the last evaluated expression for some reason.

Comment: Yep, the last expression's value is always referenced by the `_` variable.

Comment: @Chuck: Only in irb, though. If I put `23+19` and then `puts _` in an rb file and run it, I get "undefined local variable or method `_' for main:Object (NameError)".